# Как ускорить перенос данных из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe, оптимизация

У меня есть два фрейма данных `df` и `res`. `res` получен в результате группировки `df` по столбцу `name`. Теперь мне нужно в `df` переписать дынные из столбца `idxmaximum`, полученного в таблице `res`, если значение в столбце `name` таблицы `df` совпадает со значением `index` в таблице `res`

Пример `df` таблицы:

| Name | Ноябрь | Декабрь | Февраль |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Алексей | 15 | 10 | 15 |
| Алексей | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| Андрей | 15 | 25 | 15 |
| Алексей | 15 | 15 | 10 |
| Андрей | 25 | 10 | 45 |

Пример `res` таблицы:

| index | Ноябрь | Декабрь | Февраль | idxmaximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Алексей | 40 | 35 | 35 | Ноябрь |
| Андрей | 40 | 35 | 60 | Февраль |

Что хочется получить:

| Name | Ноябрь | Декабрь | Февраль | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Алексей | 15 | 10 | 15 | Ноябрь |
| Алексей | 10 | 10 | 10 | Ноябрь |
| Андрей | 15 | 25 | 15 | Февраль |
| Алексей | 15 | 15 | 10 | Ноябрь |
| Андрей | 25 | 10 | 45 | Февраль |

Мой код:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(res.shape[0]):
        if df.name[i] == res.index[j]:
            df.num[i] = res.idxmaximum[j]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить данный процесс?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на уточненный вопрос с приведенным примером данных:

```
res = df.merge(df.groupby("Name").sum().idxmax(axis=1).reset_index(name="num"), how="left")
```

результат:

```
In [112]: res
Out[112]:
      Name  Ноябрь  Декабрь  Февраль      num
0  Алексей      15       10       15   Ноябрь
1  Алексей      10       10       10   Ноябрь
2   Андрей      15       25       15  Февраль
3  Алексей      15       15       10   Ноябрь
4   Андрей      25       10       45  Февраль
```

Comment: А если у меня есть столбцы в таблице, по которым мне не нужно проводить суммирование

Comment: @Михаил, вы можете указать какие столбцы нужно просуммировать: `df.groupby("Name")[["col1", "col2", ...]].sum()...`. На будущее - __воспроизводимый__ пример данных должен учитывать такие детали )

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего можно обойтись без вспомогательной переменной `res`, воспользовавшись векторизированным решением - [groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html).

Пример:

```
In [85]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 8], [1, 4, 5], [2, 10, 11], [2, 9, 13]], columns=["id", "v1", "v2"])

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
   id  v1  v2
0   1   2   8
1   1   4   5
2   2  10  11
3   2   9  13

In [87]: df["new"] = df.groupby("id")["v2"].transform("idxmax")

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
   id  v1  v2  new
0   1   2   8    0
1   1   4   5    0
2   2  10  11    3
3   2   9  13    3
```

**NOTE:** комментарии по типу "ваш код не работает" / "у меня возникает ошибка" / etc. **не принимаются без воспроизводимого примера данных** в вопросе.

Comment: Я просто произвожу в res суммирование по столбцам
`res = df.groupby(['name']).agg({'name': [pd.Series.value_counts], 'Ноябрь':['sum'], 'Декабрь':['sum'], 'Февраль':['sum']})`